# Updating an arraylist of objects in Firestore

Tags: java, android, arraylist, google-cloud-firestore, deserialization

I have an array list of objects and I want to update my array-list with new data
but, I get an error "Could not deserialize object. Expected a List, but got a class java.util.HashMap (found in field 'students')"

here's my database
[image: I want to update the array field "students" with my new array-list of objects]

Here's the method that's responsible for updating the arraylist

```
   private void update(){
    Map<String, Object> updatedlist = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0; i<studentsList.size(); i++){
        updatedlist.put("name", studentsList.get(i).getName());
        updatedlist.put("id", studentsList.get(i).getId());
        updatedlist.put("attended", studentsList.get(i).isAttended());
    }
    DocumentReference document = db.collection("Records").document(rid);
    document.update("students", updatedlist);
}
```

for clarification, studentslist is an arraylist of students object ( List < students > studentslist ) 
I tried converting the array-list to a hash-map as well as updating the list as an array-list but I got an error from both ways.

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how you can update a property of type array.

Comment: It may seem a duplicate but, in my case I want to update the whole array not just array elements. :(

Comment: In that case you should try to add a list to the database and **not** a map.

Comment: I did and I got an error " Invalid data. Unsupported type: Models.students"